# Spring batch - env variable on yaml

Tags: spring-boot

I've classic spring batch application and I'm tryng to set datasource information using an environment variable.

Configuration look like as

```
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
url: ${JDBC_URL}
username: ${JDBC_USERNAME}
password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}
driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

If I substitute envirement var all works fine. The env var is correctly set. Inside the application if I call

```
System.getenv("JDBC_URL")
```

I get correct value

I can't use profile for different environment.